# Why is the expected length of an interval containing a point $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]/\mathbb{E}[X]$ if interval length is IID?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> In general, for processes, in which the interarrival intervals with distribution $F_X(x)$ are IID, the expected length of an arbitrary chosed interval is $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]/\mathbb{E}[X]$. We see that for the above parts, the formula is certainly valid.

Why is this statement true?

For context:

Suppose there existed an infinitely long line that is divided into IID intervals with lengths following some distribution. Let the random variable $X$ denote the length of an interval. If I arbitrarily picked a point on this line, the expected length of the interval containing this point is $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]/\mathbb{E}[X]$.

Let $\mathbb{E}[X_s]$ be the expected length from start of interval to the point.

Let $\mathbb{E}[X_e]$ be the expected length from the point to end of interval.

I understand that if such distribution is exponential, then the expected length is $\mathbb{E}[X_s] + \mathbb{E}[X_e]$, which happens to be $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]/\mathbb{E}[X]$. However, I'm not sure why this holds for the general case.

Edit:

For full context, this is taken from problem 4 on this [pset](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn07.pdf). The quote is from the [4.b) answer](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn07_sol.pdf)

Edit 2:

The interval choice strategy is to first pick a point, then choose the interval containing this point. As @user6247850 mentions, larger intervals are favored.

Comment: What does the random variable $X$ represent?

Comment: @angryavian The length of an interval.

Comment: If $X$ is an interval, the expected length of an interval is $\mathbb E[X]$. The question is rather unclear...

Comment: What is unclear about the question? For full context, this is from problem 4 on this [pset](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn07.pdf). The quoted was from the [4.b) answer](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_041F10_assn07_sol.pdf)

Comment: I think the question is posed very poorly; I don't see any difference between the distribution of $L$ (the common distribution for the length of each segment) and $R$ (the length of the segment containing the dot) since the dot doesn't affect the process of cutting the line, as Surb pointed out. From looking at the answer to part (a) where the intervals are $\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$, the setup seems to instead consider the dot as another "cut" point, and asks for the expected total length of the two adjacent intervals, which leads to $\frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Comment: @angryavian I think the difference between $R$ and $L$ is because it is more likely that a randomly chosen dot is in a longer segment than a shorter one.

Comment: This sounds very similar to the waiting-time paradox for Poisson point processes, especially considering angryavian's comment. If you have access to the second volume of Feller, it is treated in Chapter 1.4. You might also try "waiting-time bus paradox" in google for other references.

Comment: @user6247850 Thanks, that must be what is going on (in conjunction with "waiting time paradox" that Nap D. Lover mentions); choosing an interval at random is not the same as choosing an interval containing a randomly placed dot.

Comment: [This website](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2018/09/13/waiting-time-paradox/#Digging-Deeper:-Probabilities-&-Poisson-Processes) gives a mathematical explanation of $E[T^2]/E[T]$, but it hand-waves past some important details.

Comment: Note that while the exponential arrival time process is memoryless, for general distributions $X$, it is not. Therefore, the expected length of the interval containing a point will be different from point to point, depending on the distance to where the process starts. In that sense, this problem is not well posed. However, you can show that as $y\to\infty$, the expected length of the interval containing $y$ will approach $E[X^2]/E[X]$ (I don't know how, but you can).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will first take some care to make sure everything is set up rigorously. Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be the iid sequence of waiting times, all distributed like $X$, and let $T_n=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$ denote the $n^\text{th}$ arrival time.

We are interested in the length of the interval containing some particular point $t$. I will denote this by $L_t$. In mathematical terms,
$$
L_t=T_{N(t)+1}-T_{N(t)},\qquad \text{where }N(t)= \sup\{n:T_n\le t\}
$$
Finally, let
$$
\ell(t)=E[L_t]
$$

We can then prove the following theorem, which gives a rigorous interpretation to your question:

> **Theorem**: $\lim_{t\to\infty} \ell(t)=E[X^2]/E[X]$.

*Proof:* I will assume that $X$ has a pdf of $f_X(x)$ for simplicity, but this is actually not necessary. Using the law of total expectation with respect to $X_1$, we get
$$
\ell(t) = \int_0^t f_X(x) \ell(t-x)\,dx+\int_t^\infty x f_X(x)\,dx
$$
Note that $\int_t^\infty x f_X(x)\,dx=E[X\cdot {\bf 1}(X\ge t)]$ is just some function of $t$, which I will denote $g(t)$ for convenience. It is well known that $E[X]<\infty$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t)=0$ (proof: dominated convergence theorem).The above equation can be written succinctly using a convolution:
$$
\ell = f*\ell + g
$$
This convolution equation has a solution in terms of the renewal function $m(t)$, defined as follows:
$$
m(t)=E[N(t)]=E\big[\text{number of arrivals in $[0,t]$}\big]
$$
Using the methods at [this page](https://www.randomservices.org/random/renewal/Equations.html#ren4), (see box numbered $24$), we can prove that
$$
\ell(t) = g(t)+\int_0^tg(s) m'(t-s)\,ds,
$$
Now that we have "solved" for $\ell(t)$, we just need to determine its long term behavior. The [key renewal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#Key_renewal_theorem)* is exactly suited to this purpose, and says that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_0^t g(s)m'(t-s)\,ds=\frac1{E[X]}\int_0^\infty g(s)\,ds
$$
All that remains is to prove $\int_0^\infty g(s)\,ds=E[X^2]$, which is done as follows:
$$
\int_0^\infty g(s)\,ds=\int_0^\infty E[X\cdot {\bf 1}(X>s)]\,ds=E\left[X\int_0^\infty {\bf 1}(X>s)\,ds\right]=E[X\cdot X]
$$

*A condition for applying the key renewal theorem is that $\int_0^\infty g(s)\,ds <\infty$. Fortunately, the very last computation shows this is true as long as $E[X^2]<\infty$.

Comment: $ℓ(t)$ is the weighted expectation of $X_1$ if it contains $t$ and some other first interval containing $t$ if $X_1$ does not. If $X_1$ does not contain $t$, then we shift $t$ left and find the expected length of that other interval, for all possible shifts leftward. By law of total expectation, this is justified. After some manipulations of $ℓ(t)$, it is shown to approach $E[X^2]/E[X]$ as t→∞. Is this the intuition?

Comment: @Legend123 That's a good summary.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to prove this. The problem had me confused for a while. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Legend123 This is something I had been curious about for a while, so thank you for giving me the excuse to sit down and figure it out!